# How could I show popoverView when user press any cell on tableView?

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview, ios4, uipopovercontroller

I wanna when user press each cell in tableView on ipad , and then it will show a popoverView with detail Data..

But in this delegate:- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}

I can't use a sender to let popoverView show up...
Or how could I use a sender to show popoverView show up??

Thanks in advance...

Mini

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the cell by sending the following message to your tableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Or if you just want to get a CGRect then use the following method

```
- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Sorry but I still confuse a little bit ..if I got a method(-(IBAction)showDetailList:(id)sender)for press any cell on TableView to show popoverView.. How could I use this method??Thanks..

Comment: When a UITableViewCell get selected (i.e. clicked) your didSelectRowAtIndexPath will get called, then you can retrieve the cell with cellForRowAtIndexPath there and present the PopoverViewController with the cell